# Change button color on click inside ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am generating segment buttons conditionally, how can I change the button color which was clicked:

```
<ion-segment *ngIf="menu" [(ngModel)]="apps">
         <ion-segment-button *ngFor="let item of menu; let i = index" value="{{item .key}}"
                              [ngClass]="{active: i === activeIndex}" (click)="changeTab(item.key); setActiveIndex(i)"
                              style="display:block;" >

            {{item?.name}}

          </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
```

If I apply `[ngStyle]="{'background-color': this.buttonColor}"` on `ion-segment-button` then it reflect on all the button, I just want to change the color of the clicked one

Comment: `[ngClass]="{active: i === activeIndex}"` can't you just add the background color to the active class in css? Else try: `[style]=" i === activeIndex ? 'background-color: '+this.buttonColor : '' "`

Comment: @Ivaro18 did this: .active{
    background-color: #ca332e;
  } already, doesn't work

Comment: could you try `[class]=" (i == activeIndex) ? 'segment active' : 'segment'" `

Comment: Only one button that can be active at a time or multiple buttons can be active ?

Comment: try [class.active]="{ i === activeIndex}"

Comment: This solved the problem [ngStyle]=" i === activeIndex ? {'background-color': '#ca332e', 'color': '#fff'} : {'background-color': '#1B2631', 'color': '#fff'} " , thanks for all of your help